# Apply function to a certain element of a nested list

Tags: r, vector, nested

I want to substract one from a particular element of a nested list.
How should I do that?

This is my nested list
I want to one from positive values of bar vector (check first is it is positive)

x <- list(a = list(foo = 1:8, bar = 3:4), b = list(baz = 5:6))

I was thinking about map function.

Thank you!

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: $a
$a$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$a$bar
[1] 2 3


$b
$b$baz
[1] 5 6

Comment: But first giving a condition to check if the elements in bar are >0, then to subtract one from from each positive element. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a recursive function:

```
mod_at <- function(x, name, FUN){
  if(name %in% names(x)){ 
    x[[name]] <- FUN(x[[name]])
    x
  }
  else if(is.list(x))lapply(x, mod_at, name, FUN)
  else x
}
```

Now use that to modify the list:

```
mod_at(x, "bar", function(x)ifelse(x>0, x-1, x))

$a
$a$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$a$bar
[1] 2 3


$b
$b$baz
[1] 5 6
```

You could use the function the way you want:

```
mod_at(x, "baz", sqrt)

$a
$a$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$a$bar
[1] 3 4


$b
$b$baz
[1] 2.236068 2.449490
```

Comment: May I ask one a bit similar task, which I cant solve.. If yes, shall I create a new question for that?

Comment: @AnahitHovhannisyan sure go ahead create the question and you can even tag me/ post the link here

Comment: Thank you! I can post only one question in 90 min...I will post it here if it is ok, sorry for inconvinience

Comment: I have a nested vector $a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945
$a$gen
[1] 109 109 105
$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702
$b$gen
[1] 109 109 109

Comment: I want to divide the elements of $a$age to 25, round them up and the result write in $a$gen, as well as do the same with $b$age and result write in $b$gen

So the output should be $a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945
$a$gen
[1] 108 104 117
$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702
$b$gen
[1] 108 108 108

Comment: @AnahitHovhannisyan you should be able to post a question. Also I am unable to tell what the question reads like in the comments because of the formating. ie cant tell the nature of the list etc

Comment: Posted here. Thanks a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554355/apply-function-to-a-certain-element-and-rewrite-the-elements-in-another-vector-o

Comment: Hi, How would it be possible to apply the same function for an element (with a specific column name) in a list of lists? I can extract that variable with data$param[,"pops"] Thank you again!

Comment: @AnahitHovhannisyan this function is recursive. Yes you can use it, as long as the innermost element is atomic. Check the solution I gave in the other question you asked

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I think my element is not atomic? as I am not able to reach it with $ and the function is not changing my element values

Comment: Atomic elements are `arrays, matrices, vectors` but not `lists`. You will have to ask your question. I am unable to tell what you have and what you are doing. Just ask the question, and you can put the link here and see whether I can help. Also by asking the question, you will get help from others too

Comment: Thank you! It is atomic, but still I am a bit confused with the data. Tried to explain it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618434/nested-lists-and-function-to-some-elements

Comment: Implementing your function with my new data was not changing anything, so my guess was that maybe it is not a proper input file. I was using this --- data<-mod_at(data, "pops", function(x)ifelse(x<0.125, 0.125, x)). Also was trying to understand your function per line but was a bit struggling. Would it be possible to give a short description on the lines of the function? Thank you!

Comment: in the `mod_at` function, change the `x[[name]]` into `x[, name]` and then use `FUN` to be `FUN = function(x)pmax(x, 0.125)`