# Apply function to a certain element and rewrite the elements in another vector of a nested list

Tags: r, vector, nested

I have a nested vector

```
$a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945
$a$gen
[1] 109 109 105
$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702
$b$gen
[1] 109 109 109
```

I want to divide the elements of $a$age to 25, round them up and the result write in $a$gen, as well as do the same with $b$age and result write in $b$gen

So the output should be

```
$a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945
$a$gen
[1] 108 104 117
$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702
$b$gen
[1] 108 108 108
```

Comment: Round them up to lowest number, so it it is 108.25 I will have 108 in my vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to solve, although you could tackle the problem as :

```
x %>%
  map_df(data.frame, .id='grp')%>%
  mutate(gen = abs(ceiling(age/25)))%>%
  split(~grp)%>%
  map(~as.list(.x[-1]))


$a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945

$a$gen
[1] 108 104 117


$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702

$b$gen
[1] 108 108 108
```

Answer (score 1):

using the previous solution:

```
mod_at1 <- function(x, name, FUN, new_name = NULL){
  
  if(name %in% names(x)){ 
    x[[if(is.null(new_name)) name else new_name]] <- FUN(x[[name]])
    x
  }
  else if(is.list(x))lapply(x, mod_at1, name, FUN, new_name)
  else x
}

mod_at1(x, 'age', function(x)abs(ceiling(x/25)), 'gen')
$a
$a$age
[1] -2702 -2621 -2945

$a$gen
[1] 108 104 117


$b
$b$age
[1] -2702 -2702 -2702

$b$gen
[1] 108 108 108
```