# Nested lists and function to some elements

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list data

With str(data) I have the following output

```
List of 2
$ group_info                  :List of 2
  ..$ lat       : num [1:22] 50.5 55 ...
  ..$ names     : chr [1:22] "A" "B" 
$ param                   : num [1:60, 1:56] 0.0923 0.0952 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:60] "RESULTS" "RESULTS1" "RESULTS2" "RESULTS3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:56] "exp" "pops" ...
```

I would like to check the values in "pops" column and if them are <0.125, then give then value of 0.125.

How would it be possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to extract the `list` element and assign back with `pmax` of the column and 0.125, thus if any element is less than 0.125, it will still return 0.125

```
data$param[, "pops"] <- pmax(data$param[, "pops"], 0.125, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or if we want to use the `<`, either `ifelse` or `replace` would work

```
data$param[, "pops"] <- replace(data$param[, "pops"], 
                                data$param[, "pops"] < 0.125, 0.125)
```